# Reliable Research Resources for RPG Creation?

Tags: game-design, statistics

I'm an Ozstralian enthusiast of ALL genres of game, electronic & tabletop, but mostly here to network resources for research & rules generation for a new line of fantasy / Medieval roleplaying game products I am creating...If you can help me to connect to good resources in those areas, please reply post - I've been manually searching here & elsewhere across the web with decidely mixed success for some time.

I'm particularly interested in reliable data / facts / statistics that can help me generate ability score / stat & encumberance / movement tables as realistically as reasonably possible (answering questions like "How much can the average / STRongest human being lift or carry without getting slowed down?", "How fast & for how long can a human being walk / jog / run?" etc) *without copying content en masse from existing systems.*

Comment: Hi cre8vnova, welcome to RPG.SE! Check out our [tour] for how we work here. The request you're making is enormously too broad for us; I think you might be here a bit too early in your game design process. The RPG market is thousands of games strong, and we can't really point you to just arbitrary resources connected to designing the dominant type of game on the market. We specialise in answering or solving specific questions and problems that can have a single best solution or answer. You could ask this on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/1204) however.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [GNS model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNS_theory)?

Comment: I am familiar with the GNS model.  I'm seeking this sort of information because I have a simulationist bent, although the gameplay of my system will feature solid narrativist elements.